# su does not change prompt to #

Tags: root-access

I am trying to root a device.
I have pushed su , busybox to device, 
but on doing "su", it seems that I have no root privilege:

```
shell@nemo:/ $ su
1|shell@nemo:/ $

1|shell@nemo:/ $ whoami
shell
shell@nemo:/ $
```

How can I understand what's wrong with su and how to fix it ?

**EDIT**:

I am actually trying to root LG W200 device, having real trouble with it.

EDIT2:

I've set 7777 permission (suid), but it still fails.

```
chmod 7777 su-arm

 shell@nemo:/ $ ls -al /system/xbin/su-arm
-rwsrwsrwt root     shell      467952 2016-11-20 12:01 su-arm
shell@nemo:/ $ su-arm
255|shell@nemo:/ $ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0
shell@nemo:/ $whoami
shell
```

EDIT3: I've updated su binary and busybox binary, but each now fails differently:

```
shell@nemo:/ $ busybox su
su: unknown user root
1|shell@nemo:/ $ su
error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.
1|shell@nemo:/ $
```

Thanks,
Ranchu

Comment: It's quite clear from the "1|" beside _shell@nemo_ that the command failed. It did not return 0 (success).

Answer (score 0):

You have to unlock the bootloader first. Here is a page to help you do it:

https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/downloads.html

Here are step by step instructions:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/watch-urbane/development/everything-urbane-root-how-tos-files-t3243975

That page also contains the files you need to flash.

**IF YOU ARE NEW TO THIS PLEASE READ THE POST ENTIRELY BEFORE TRYING TO FLASH OR INSTALL ANYTHING. I TAKE NO RESPONSIBILITY FOR ANYTHING YOU DO TO YOUR DEVICE.**

Comment: Thanks. I work with this page for some days now. But everything there does not work on my device. trying to flash even boot.img or system.img fail to start. probably it does not fit my watch ? different bootloader (I wish I xda provided bootloader too to flash) ? I don't understand. I work with images for urbane from https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/downloads.html, but any binary update from this xda link, fails.

Comment: now I get "unknown user root" , I've edited the message. Also the link from xda did not help in my device. not sure why.